# Using Operator Module to Pass 'Nothing'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The code below executes fine when the third condition and choice are removed.

I am using the `operator` module to pass in a tilde.

The problem is that there are times where I want to NOT take the inverse of these statements, and other times that I do.

In the `conditions` section, I am passing `None` to avoid using an operator there, but this is obviously incorrect. I also tried using an `if` statement to avoid using the inverse operator, i but don't know how to connect `if` statements with an `&`.

FWIW - I realize I could define all the possible `specs` individually, but there are more than a dozen of them, so this approach seemed a lot better to me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from operator import lt as less_than, invert as invrt
import math

infinity = math.inf

names = [
    [5, 'b0524', .02, 'shoes'],
    [1, 'b0874', .12, 'toy'],
    [10, 'b0321', .11, 'b0321'],
    [7, 'b0781', .60, 'car'],
    [8, 'b0321', .16, 'plane']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['orders', 'id', 'acos', 'term'])

acos = .15
exclude = ['toy']


def specs(df, min_orders, max_orders, operator, acos, exclude, tilde1, tilde2):
    return (
    (df['orders'] >= min_orders) &
    (df['orders'] <= max_orders) &
    (operator(df['acos'], acos)) &
    (tilde1(df['term'].str.contains('|'.join(exclude)))) &
    (tilde2(df['term'].str.contains(pat = 'b0', case = False)))
    )


def strategy(df, acos, exclude):
    conditions = ([
        specs(df, 3, infinity, less_than, acos, exclude, invrt, invrt),
        specs(df, 1, 2, less_than, acos, exclude, invrt, invrt),   
        specs(df, 1, 2, less_than, acos, exclude, None, None),    
    ])


    choices = [
        'strat1',
        'strat2',
        'strat3'
    ]


    df['strategy'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='NA')
    return df


strategy(df, acos, exclude)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work. The idea is to use a `conditional expression` (aka `ternary operator`) to toggle between actually calling `tilde2` vs simply returning a like-sized result filled with `True` (there may be a more elegant way to do this, but I have gotten the array of `True` by comparing `df['term']` to itself for equality, which will always be `True`).

```py
def specs(df, min_orders, max_orders, operator, acos, exclude, tilde1, tilde2):
    return (
    (df['orders'] >= min_orders) &
    (df['orders'] <= max_orders) &
    (operator(df['acos'], acos)) &
    (tilde1(df['term'].str.contains('|'.join(exclude)))) &
    (df['term'] == df['term'] if tilde2 is None else tilde2(df['term'].str.contains(pat = 'b0', case = False)))
    )
```

Comment: Why does this not work when it is structured like a normal 'If' 'Else' structure? ie.  if tilde2 is None: df['term'] == df['term]   Else: tilde2(df['term'].str.contains(pat = 'b0', case = False))

Comment: @anarchocaps This code uses a "conditional expression" (<https://peps.python.org/pep-0308/>) which is basically in the form `expression1 if condition else expression2` and can be used as a part of a single Python statement. In a regular if/else structure the code following `if` is a statement (not just an expression) and the code following `else` is another statement. The way `specs()` is currently written, it's all one statement `return ( ... )`. You could use regular if/else, buy only by splitting it into two statements: `if tilde2 is None: return expr1; else: return expr2`.